# jQuery animate not shaking the element

Tags: jquery

Doing a form validation. If field fails validation, I wish to change color and shake the field. My code:

```
$('#'+vet)
.css({'background-color':'yellow','border-color':'red'})
.animate({ left: "-10px" }, 100).animate({ left: "10px" }, 100)
.animate({ left: "-10px" }, 100).animate({ left: "10px" }, 100)
.animate({ left: "0px" }, 100);
```

It does change the field background and border colors, but the field doesn't shake.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Alternatively, use jQuery UI's shake effect. http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field's [`position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to `relative`:

```
input {
    position : relative;
}
```

(Using whatever selector makes the most sense for your structure.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt7JW/

By default elements have `static` positioning for which setting `left` (and `top`, etc.) has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Using the left, top, right, bottom properties to change the position of an element, it also has to have a positioning context:

```
.element { position: relative; }
```

or

```
.element { position: absolute; }
```

or

```
.element { position: fixed; }
```

Depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try linking animations in a callback method that you can pass into the `animate()` method, instead of directly chaining the animates together. jQuery docs state:

> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the animation is complete. This >can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence.

I'm guessing the reason its not currently moving is that it is trying to animate in opposite directions at the same time. This is untested but try :

```
$('#' + vet).css({'background-color':'yellow', 'border-color':'red' })
.animate({ left: '-=10px'}, 100, function() {
   $('#' + vet).animate({left: '+=20px'}, 100, function() {
     $('#' + vet).animate({left: '-=20px'}, 100, function() {
        $('#' + vet).animate({left: '+=10px'}, 100);
     });
   });
});
```

Using `+=` also eliminates setting the position to relative. Now each animation carries out as the last one finishes.

Edit: `.animate().animate()` seems to be the same as this after all.

Comment: Using callbacks is _not_ necessary for animations on the same element. All jQuery animation methods (not just `.animate()`) are designed to automatically queue one after the other if used on the same element so chaining is the correct and normal way to do it. You _do_ need to use callbacks if you want to animate a second element after the first's animation finishes - animation effects on multiple elements will otherwise happen simultaneously. _"Using += also eliminates setting the position to relative."_ - No it doesn't.